# Rotate several rectangles about common point in Julia using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I am trying to rotate a set of rectangles that should represent a car in Julia using matplotlib. The following code works. However, when I am trying to rotate the car, it looks like the it becomes thicker as it approaches 90 degrees. Here is the code:

```
using PyCall
using PyPlot
@pyimport matplotlib.animation as animation
@pyimport matplotlib.patches as patches
@pyimport matplotlib as mpl




function drawCar(pos::Array{Float64})

    x = pos[1]
    y = pos[2]
    psi = pos[3]
    pos = [x;y]

    # define outer car geometry
    length = 36.5 / 100.0
    width = 20.0 / 100.0
    btmLeft_vertex = pos + [-length/2,-width/2]


    # define tire geometry
    tire_width = 2.0/100.0
    tire_length = 5.0/100.0
    tire_distance = 8.0/100.0

    # define patches that make up the car's appearance
    # car for outer boundary and tires at tl=top left, tr=top right, bl=bottom left, br=bottom right
    car = patches.Rectangle(btmLeft_vertex,length,width,fill=false, linewidth=3.0,color="black")
    tl = patches.Rectangle(pos + [-tire_distance-tire_length,width/2-tire_width],tire_length,tire_width,color="black")
    tr = patches.Rectangle(pos + [tire_distance,width/2-tire_width],tire_length,tire_width,color="black")
    bl = patches.Rectangle(pos + [-tire_distance-tire_length,-width/2],tire_length,tire_width,color="black")
    br = patches.Rectangle(pos + [tire_distance,-width/2],tire_length,tire_width,color="black")

    car_parts = [car,tl,tr,bl,br]

    return car_parts    
end

function updateCarParts(fig,car_parts,angle)


    ax = gca()
    # define a rotation transformation and a transformation from data coordinate system to display coordinate system
    t1 = mpl.transforms[:Affine2D]()
    t1[:rotate_deg_around](0.0,0.0, angle)
    t2 = ax[:transData]
    # combine transformations
    t3 = t1[:__add__](t2)

    # apply rotation transformation to all car parts
    for p in car_parts
      p[:set_transform](t3)
     end
     return car_parts

end


# Play / Start the animation 
function play()

    fig = figure()
    hold(true)

    # define initial position and orientation of the car
    pos = [0.0,0.0,0.0]

    # get the patches that make up the car and add them to the current figure
    car_parts = drawCar(pos)
    ax = gca()
    for p in car_parts
        ax[:add_patch](p)
    end

    # define animation function
    function animate(frameNum)
      frameNum += 1
      # update the orientation of the car parts
      angle = frameNum
      car_parts = updateCarParts(fig,car_parts,angle)
      return nothing
    end

  # define animation object
  anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=50,repeat=true)
  axis([-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5],"equal")
  grid(true, which="both")

  end
```

I don't see, what I am doing wrong. Thank you for your help.

**Edit:** Here are two images with 0 degrees (top) and rotated with 90 degrees (bottom). The car in the bottom image appears thicker.
[image: slim car (0 deg)]
[image: thick car (90 deg)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe (not tested) that you need the
`axis([-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5], "equal")` 
when you do each plot, i.e. in the `animate` function.

Comment: Thank you. But this doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: Can you show pictures of the issue? Does something different happen in Python?

Comment: I added two images for explanation

Comment: Indeed this looks like it's just a problem with the aspect ratio, as I predicted. (i.e. the distance between -0.4 and -0.2 is different on the x and y axes.) Try moving the `axis` command around (or adding more of the same command) until you find the right place for it. In any case, this is a question about matplotlib, not Julia.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the axis equal command at the end of the play() function solved the problem. Thank you David P. Sanders.

Here is the updated code:

```
 using PyCall
 using PyPlot
 @pyimport matplotlib.animation as animation
 @pyimport matplotlib.patches as patches
 @pyimport matplotlib as mpl

function drawCar(pos::Array{Float64})
    x = pos[1]
    y = pos[2]
    psi = pos[3]
    pos = [x;y]

    # define outer car geometry
    length = 36.5 / 100.0
    width = 20.0 / 100.0
    btmLeft_vertex = pos + [-length/2,-width/2]


    # define tire geometry
    tire_width = 2.0/100.0
    tire_length = 5.0/100.0
    tire_distance = 8.0/100.0

    # define patches that make up the car's appearance
    # car for outer boundary and tires at tl=top left, tr=top right, bl=bottom left, br=bottom right
    car = patches.Rectangle(btmLeft_vertex,length,width,fill=false, linewidth=3.0,color="black")
    tl = patches.Rectangle(pos + [-tire_distance-tire_length,width/2-tire_width],tire_length,tire_width,color="black")
    tr = patches.Rectangle(pos + [tire_distance,width/2-tire_width],tire_length,tire_width,color="black")
    bl = patches.Rectangle(pos + [-tire_distance-tire_length,-width/2],tire_length,tire_width,color="black")
    br = patches.Rectangle(pos + [tire_distance,-width/2],tire_length,tire_width,color="black")

    car_parts = [car,tl,tr,bl,br]

    return car_parts    
end

function updateCarParts(fig,car_parts,angle)
    ax = gca()
    # define a rotation transformation and a transformation from data coordinate system to display coordinate system
    t1 = mpl.transforms[:Affine2D]()
    t1[:rotate_deg_around](0.0,0.0, angle)
    t2 = ax[:transData]
    # combine transformations
    t3 = t1[:__add__](t2)

    # apply rotation transformation to all car parts
    for p in car_parts
      p[:set_transform](t3)
  end
  return car_parts
end

# Play / Start the animation 
function play()

    fig = figure()
    hold(true)

    # define initial position and orientation of the car
    pos = [0.0,0.0,0.0]

    # get the patches that make up the car and add them to the current figure
    car_parts = drawCar(pos)
    ax = gca()
    for p in car_parts
        ax[:add_patch](p)
    end

    # define animation function
    function animate(frameNum)
      frameNum += 1
      # update the orientation of the car parts
      angle = frameNum
      car_parts = updateCarParts(fig,car_parts,angle)
      return nothing
    end

  # define animation object
  anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=50,repeat=true)
  grid(true, which="both")
  ax[:set_xlim]([-0.5,0.5])
  ax[:set_ylim]([-0.5,0.5])
  ax[:set_aspect]("equal")
end
```